# NodeJS - SQL Server connection closed

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I'm trying to call a register stored procedure from SQL Server. I'm using NodeJS with the `mssql` package. I got most of the code from the `mssql` Npm documentation. But it still doesn't work.

The code basically tries to initiate a `ConnectionPool` as a read the last update renamed connection to `ConnectionPool`, create a new request, introduce the parameters and the execute the stored procedure. I have it this way because I need to change the connection variable to another database every once in a while.

The error I get is:

> ConnectionError: Connection is closed.

My code:

```
const sql = require('mssql');

const config = require('../config/dbPoly');

module.exports.registerUser = function(pUserName, pPassword, pNombre, pApellidos, pFK_TipoUsuario, callback) {

  var connection = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
  var request = new sql.Request(connection);
  request.input('input_parameter', sql.VARCHAR(25), pUserName);
  request.input('input_parameter', sql.VARCHAR(16), pPassword);
  request.input('input_parameter', sql.VARCHAR(25), pNombre);
  request.input('input_parameter', sql.VARCHAR(50), pApellidos);
  request.input('input_parameter', sql.Int, pFK_TipoUsuario);

  request.execute('RegistrarUsuario', (err, result)=>{
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this async version of implementation. Check if this serves your purpose

```
const sql = require('mssql');

const config = require('../config/dbPoly');

module.exports.registerUser = async function(pUserName, pPassword, pNombre, pApellidos, pFK_TipoUsuario) {

    try {

        let connection = await sql.connect(config)

        let result = await connection.request()
            .input('input_parameter', sql.VARCHAR(25), pUserName);
            .input('input_parameter', sql.VARCHAR(16), pPassword);
            .input('input_parameter', sql.VARCHAR(25), pNombre);
            .input('input_parameter', sql.VARCHAR(50), pApellidos);
            .input('input_parameter', sql.Int, pFK_TipoUsuario);
            .execute('RegistrarUsuario');

        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err); // ... error checks 
    }

};

sql.on('error', err => {
    // ... error handler 
})
```

Comment: Remove the port config, as it is default `1443`. Don't use if using named instance

Comment: So your problem solved ? Upvote if found helpful, you are welcome!

Comment: Actually as that code is, node send the following error: Request error :RequestError: Procedure or function 'RegistrarUsuario' expects parameter '@pNombreUsuario', which was not supplied.  Any ideas.

Comment: What is exact the stored procedure syntax of mssql you are calling ? You might be missing input or output parameter there to pass from node.

Comment: The parameters are supposed to be added to the request by calling request.input() like I did in the corrected code in this thread. But it still gives me the same error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930584/running-sql-server-stored-procedure-from-nodejs/44931329#44931329

Comment: That is true, but you are calling some stored procedure on server. Do you have that, just to verify if we are passing the write parameters ?

Comment: These are the parameter the stored procedure recieves, i had to take the @ out of them because of stackoverflow:  pNombreUsuario VARCHAR(25),
  pPassword VARCHAR(16),
  pNombre VARCHAR(25),
  pApellidos VARCHAR(50),
  pFK_TipoUsuario INT

Comment: yeah that is correct, but is pNombreUsuario an input or output param for the procedure ?

Comment: It is an input parameter for the procedure. All those are the parameters it needs to insert in the columns of the table.

Comment: Strange if its an input param, it should accept as per the documentation. I am really not sure about the one mate.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else faces this problem, Prabodh's answer works perfectly.

I then faced another problem, it said the localhost was undefined in 1500ms. The reason was because my server field in the json config file had the following format: 'localhost\Server-Name'. I changed it just 'localhost' and problem fixed.

Also make sure your server has SQL Authentication enabled and not just Windows Authentication.

Comment: Also if you are using named instance, avoid adding `port` in config as per the documentation of the module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#general-same-for-all-drivers